# Can you use `jquery $.when()` for continue statement?

Tags: javascript

Say I've got a JS function:

```
function x() { 
   // do something
   outerFunction();
   // do more stuff
}
```

I know that you can do something like:

```
function x() {
    // do something
    $.when(outerFunction()).then(anotherFunction());
}
```

I can continue running (I.e. go to `// do more stuff`) **ONLY WHEN** `outerFunction` completed run? something like:

```
 function x() {
    // do something
    $.when(outerFunction()).then(continue);
    // do more stuff
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: No,  `continue` only makes sense inside of a loop, and like you said `continue` is a statement, therefore you cannot use it as an expression.

Comment: `$.when(outerFunction()).then(anotherFunction());` - the second pair of `()` is wrong there.

Comment: @elclanrs - I know - I meant something like this.

Answer (score 0):

`outerFunction()` *always* completes to run before the stuff after it is executed.

Of course, it might start something asynchronous, and return a promise for it. Then you have to do

```
function x() {
    // do something
    return outerFunction().then(function(result) {
       // do more stuff
    });
}
```

Notice there's no need to call `$.when` when `outerFunction` already returns a promise, and there's no reason to use it at all when it doesn't return one.